# How do I open the Resources Window in Blend for VS2022?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-2022, expression-blend

The "Resources" pane in Microsoft Blend for Visual Studio appears to be broken.
I have confirmed the Resources Pane working in VS2017, and VS2019.

In VS2017 and VS2019, it is located under: **View >> Resources Window**

The hotkey **CTRL+SHIFT+E** is also supposed to open it.
However the Resources Pane does not respond to this hotkey.
I have reset hotkeys, and assigned my own unique one. These do not do anything either.

I have attempted to export settings from VS2017 and VS2019 to get it to open. That does not work either.

How do I open it?

[image: Visual Studio 2017]

[image: Visual Studio 2019]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Resource View missing problem is still under review.
Please vote on the thread: [Microsoft blend for visual studio 2022: resources window missing on WPF project](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/microsoft-blend-for-visual-studio-2022:-/1584204#:%7E:text=The%20reason%20the%20resources%20window,windows%20were%20no%20longer%20supported.)